# Having trouble pushing a commit to Git on OSX

Tags: macos, git

I'm a new Git user and I'm having trouble getting my first commit working. I'm using the Terminal in OSX. What I've done so far:

1) I've set up my GitHub account and added a repository
2) I've created an SSH key and added it to my account
3) I've tested my connection to the domain and Github says I've successfully authenticated.
4) I've set up my repository on my local system using:

```
echo "# test" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/fakename/test.git
git push -u origin master
```

And I get the error:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname https: nodename nor servname provided,
>   or not known fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

In my ~/ssh director I have the files id_rsa, id_rsa.pub and known_hosts. I have no ssh config file.

What am I missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use authentication with ssh, you need to use the following scheme:

```
git@github.com:<username>/<repository>.git
```

If you already added remote, you can change the URL like this:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:fakename/test.git
```

Or same result but with two commands:

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:fakename/test.git
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Could you explain HOW/WHY this works? I have no prior experience with SSH or remote logins.

Answer (score 0):

I quickly gave up on the terminal git commands as it becomes too many commands to remember, instead I have good results with the `GitHub for Mac.app` and committing, pushing and pulling directly from `Xcode`. - Looking at your commands I’d say probably the repository does not exist on remote, and therefor rejects the push?

Comment: Yeah. I'm sure I'll eventually end up using the client. Right now, I've been taking a Linux course so I've been putting myself on a diet of command line only :)